# Availability of clustering function in QGIS development core for Field Calculator tool

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, clustering

I would like to use Field Calc to calculate the points CLUSTER_ID and update an existing field table.

Apart from the Processing Toolbox 'DBSCAN clustering' and 'K-means clustering' applications that creates a new layer, my interest is using, for example, a function such as (non-existent) `kmeans_points ($geometry, 6)`. It seems that in the latest versions of QGIS there is no function with these capabilities. And I don't know if QGIS development team has plans to implement in the development core a geometry function to calculate clusterings that will be available to build expressions.

I ask for help to build a expression that can be executed for Field Calc that allows to update a existing field with the CLUSTER_IDs to provides some clustering or pseudo-clustering method (as does the K-means algorithm using the distance between each point and a centroid) that makes a partition in a dataset.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. A long bullet list of questions generally results in quick closure. Please [Edit] the Question to ask only one question.

Comment: hi. Expressions are evaluated one time for each feature, but it seems to me that you want to create clusters just one time instead of features count times. Create the clusters in a new layer, then get in the field calculator the cluster id for the current feature.

Comment: Exactly, I want to create clusters only once instead of geometry features, as I want to avoid duplicating a layer. I don't understand what you mean by 'then get in the field calculator the cluster id for the current feature'. Do you mean to make a join to transfer the CLUSTER_ID from the layer created with the tool 'K-means clustering' to the initial layer?

Comment: Yes. You can get the attribute from the clusters layer. The cluster id or the cluster count. if your layer has some feature id atrribute, then _attribute(get_feature('Clusters', 'fid', "fid"), 'CLUSTER_COUNT')_ can be used

Comment: I will use this alternative. It fits perfectly with the work I am doing